# How to write this LINQ in lambda form?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I write this query in lambda form?

```
var result = from email in emails
             join relation in relations on email.Id equals relation.EmailId into g
             join contact in contacts on g.Max(x => x.ContactId) equals contact.Id
             select new MyRowModel
             {
                 Id = email.Id,
                 LastName = contact.LastName,
                 FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                 SentOn = email.SentDate,
                 Subject = email.Subject
             };
```

Comment: FYI. That's called query syntax and what you are calling "lambda form" is called method syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Sry for not searching harder :)